# MySQL- how to get data from 3 table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query which retrieve data from 1 table based on 3 table:

### Table1

UID | GID
1  |  0
2  |  1
3  |  1
4  |  2

### Table2

CID | UID
1  |  2
2  |  3
3  |  4
4  |  5

### Table3

LID | CID
1  |  2
2  |  2
3  |  3
4  |  1

Now I need to retrieve data from table3 where table1.GID=1 and table2.UID=table1.UID and table3.CID=table2.CID

Comment: Are you familiar with JOINs in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT Table3.* FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN (Table2, Table3) 
ON (table1.GID=1 and table2.UID=table1.UID and table3.CID=table2.CID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I made a typo

```
SELECT 
    t3.*
FROM
    t3
        LEFT JOIN
    t2 ON t3.cid = t2.cid
        LEFT JOIN
    t1 ON t2.uid = t1.uid
WHERE
    t1.gid = 1;
```

With tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `t1` (`uid`, `gid`) VALUES
(1, 0),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `t2` (`cid`, `uid`) VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 4),
(4, 5);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t3` (
  `lid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `t3` (`lid`, `cid`) VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 3),
(4, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT table3.* 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 
JOIN table3 
WHERE table1.GID=1 
and table2.UID=table1.UID 
and table3.CID=table2.CID
```

Comment: Please don't give answers that promote non-ANSi join patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table3.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.UID = table2.UID)
INNER JOIN table3 ON (table3.CID = table2.CID)
WHERE table1.GID = 1
```

Comment: Why `INNER` and not `LEFT`?

Comment: @IanMcLaird Because we're joining `table3` and definitely want data from there.